# How to remove "Quick edit" option in "register_post_meta" list page

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using `register_post_type` in list page automatically it is four actions Edit/Quick Edit/trash/View. I want to remove "Quick edit" option from list page. How I can do this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
/*------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    remove quick edit for custom post type videos just to check if less mem consumption
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
add_filter( 'post_row_actions', 'remove_row_actions', 10, 2 );
function remove_row_actions( $actions, $post )
{
  global $current_screen;
    if( $current_screen->post_type != 'videos' ) return $actions;
    unset( $actions['edit'] );
    unset( $actions['view'] );
    unset( $actions['trash'] );
    unset( $actions['inline hide-if-no-js'] );
    //$actions['inline hide-if-no-js'] .= __( 'Quick&nbsp;Edit' );

    return $actions;
}
```

It worked for me check with yours